# Python find other Python scripts in Azure Databricks folder

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I am running Microsoft Azure Databricks. I want to find files located in a folder named "tables".

[image]

The code is working when I run it locally in Pycharm on my Windows 10 computer. However when I run it in Databricks it failes.

**My code:**

```
import os
from os.path import isfile, join

working_dir = os.getcwd()
print(f"working dir = {working_dir}")
mypath = f"{working_dir}/tables"
files = [f for f in os.listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
for file in files:
    print(f"{file}")
```

**Output in Windows 10:**

```
C:\Users\bruker\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/bruker/PycharmProjects/test/test.py
working dir = C:\Users\bruker\PycharmProjects\test
1
2
```

**Databricks error:**

```
working dir = /databricks/driver
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/databricks/driver/tables'
```

I can see the files in Microsoft Azure Databricks. The script is running from `db-adapter`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The notebooks created using the `workspace` tab in Databricks all have the working directory as `databricks/driver`. The following is a python script I created under `workspace` tab and the output of current working directory.

[image]

[image]

I have reproduced your repo folder structure. When you run the code in the notebook `repo_db-adapter_notebook`, your working directory will be `/Workspace/Repos/<repo_folder_structure>/dao` .

[image]

[image]

So, please re-check and run the notebook inside your `dao` folder in your repo folder structure in order to get the correct output.